# How to get end date & time when only start date is given

Tags: php

How to get end date & time when only start date is given.

I have start `date & time(2015-10-28 16:59:23)` so how can I get end date & time where duration will be for 1 year.

```
$startd&t = $getdetails['date_time'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`strtotime`**

```
<?php
   $date = "2015-11-10";
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. ' + 365 days'));
?>
```

Or, of you are running PHP 5.2

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2015-11-10');
  $date->modify('+365 day');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

> Depending on the day of the month, you may get a different response. 
>   For a **non-leap year**, you'll get March if the *current day of the
>   month* is the 29th, 30th or 31st.  If it's a **leap year**, you'll get
>   March on the 30th or 31st of the month.  The same thing will happen on
>   the 31st of any month when you pass in the name of any month with less
>   than 31 days.  This happens because the strtotime() function will fill
>   in missing parts from the current day.
>   [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: it starts at 10 nov so how can i get time??

Comment: its just a matters of strings you add, how to format a date. check the updated

Comment: it will take leap year also?

Comment: if we are putting Y M D H i s

Comment: like this echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date. ' + 365 days')); so its taking system date and time and calculating 1 year time by system date and time

Comment: Offcourse, it will add the 365 days in the `2015-11-10` date and return you the output

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description as an alternate solution to it please try executing following code snippet.

strtotime() is php function utilized to parse a datetime string which generates unix timestamp which when passed as argument to date function retrieves datetime according to timestamp.

```
$startd&t = $getdetails['date_time'];
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($startd&t. ' + 1 year'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2015-10-28 16:59:23')) . " +1 years"));
```